# Php non-blocking soap client

Tags: php, soap, nonblocking

I'm using a lot of webservices a huge php application.
Normally all of of them send me data in ten seconds or less but sometimes I've got one who doesn't respond and freeze all the process.

So my question is how can I use a soap webservice in php without freeze all the system if it doesn't respond after a defined time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not support multithreading and asynchronous programming. However, you can `fork` another process which will perform this SOAP request; of course, you won't be able to send some data to the client from this new process, but you will be able to e.g. write its response to DB.

Comment: Just want to say that forking in php is achieved by calling a script through the command line!

Comment: So the only solution I have it's to use another technology to make my SOAP request ?

Comment: Just wanted to bump this question with a pretty useful Asynchronous soap wrapper library: http://en.dklab.ru/lib/Dklab_SoapClient/

Answer (score 2):

The solution does not necessary has to do with multithreading [penartur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831314/penartur). The only thing to do is to use I/O multiplexing using non-blocking streams and using select() function as [nutrija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343996/nutrija) suggests. One already implemented solution might be found in this link:  [Making PHP’s SOAP client asynchronous](http://www.halon.se/blog/making-phps-soap-client-asynchronous/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to make an AJAX call to another PHP file that will make the SOAP request.

Comment: I already use something like this, I call 5 differents webservices through a php script with an Ajax query, but if one of them don't respond the script continue to run and I never obtain any results :(

Comment: Do the php scripts that you call using AJAX use $_SESSION data?

Comment: try putting session_write_close() at the start of your php scripts that are being called with AJAX

Answer (score -1):

You can use [stream_set_blocking](http://php.net/stream_set_blocking) to set http/https stream to non-blocking mode.